# How to place our own chaincode that is wirtten in node.js in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

i am new in hyperledger fabric i make changes in existing fabcar.go but changes are not accepted every time previous chanincode run plz tell me how to changes accepted and my modify chaincode run?
and if  i wrote chaincode for univerty records management in node.js but i am confuse where i place the link and where is following path in located in our local machine (/opt/gopath/src/github.com/) and how to mount my own chaincode folder with docker cli container i am very confuse my new chaincode in located in (sample-fabric/chaincode/uni/node/uni.js) tell me all things in details plzzz

Comment: are you using cli container in your docker-compose.yaml file?

Answer (score 0):

To mount the directory which contains you chaincode with the cli container you need to add this line in your docker-compose.yaml file.

```
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    //other stuff
    volumes:
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
```